# C: Behaviour of arrays when assigned to pointers

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  char * ptr;

  ptr = "hello";


  printf("%p %s" ,"hello",ptr );

  getchar();

}
```

Hi, I am trying to understand clearly how can arrays get assign in to pointers. I notice when you assign an array of chars to a pointer of chars `ptr="hello";` the array decays to the pointer, but in this case I am assigning a char of arrays that are not inside a variable and not a variable containing them ", does this way of assignment take a memory address specially for `"Hello"` (what obviously is happening) , and is it possible to modify the value of each element in "Hello" wich are contained in the memory address where this array is stored. As a comparison, is it fine for me to assign a pointer with an array for example of **ints** something as vague as this`int_ptr = 5,3,4,3;` and the values 5,3,4,3 get located in a memory address as "Hello" did. And if not why is it possible only with strings? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"hello"` is a string literal. It is a nameless non-modifiable object of type `char [6]`. It is an array, and it behaves the same way any other array does. The fact that it is nameless does not really change anything. You can use it with `[]` operator for example, as in `"hello"[3]` and so on. Just like any other array, it can and will decay to pointer in most contexts.

You cannot modify the contents of a string literal because it is non-modifiable by definition. It can be physically stored in read-only memory. It can overlap other string literals, if they contain common sub-sequences of characters.

Similar functionality exists for other array types through *compound literal* syntax

```
int *p = (int []) { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

In this case the right-hand side is a nameless object of type `int [5]`, which decays to `int *` pointer. Compound literals are modifiable though, meaning that you can do `p[3] = 8` and thus replace `4` with `8`.

You can also use compound literal syntax with char arrays and do

```
char *p = (char []) { "hello" };
```

In this case the right-hand side is a modifiable nameless object of type `char [6]`.

Comment: @newacct: Yes, but I believe we are already well past the point when it has to be mentioned explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

The string literal `"hello"` is an expression of type `char[6]` (5 characters for "hello" plus one for the terminating `'\0'`). It refers to an anonymous array object with static storage duration, initialized at program startup to contain those 6 character values.

In most contexts, an expression of array type is implicitly converted a pointer to the first element of the array; the exceptions are:

- When it's the argument of `sizeof` (`sizeof "hello"` yields 6, not the size of a pointer);
- When it's the argument of `_Alignof` (a new feature in C11);
- When it's the argument of unary `&` (`&arr` yields the address of the entire array, not of its first element; same memory location, different type); and
- When it's a string literal in an initializer used to initialize an array object (`char s[6] = "hello";` copies the whole array, not just a pointer).

None of these exceptions apply to your code:

```
char *ptr;
ptr = "hello";
```

So the expression `"hello"` is converted to ("decays" to) a pointer to the first element (`'h'`) of that anonymous array object I mentioned above.

So `*ptr == 'h'`, and you can advance `ptr` through memory to access the other characters: `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`, and `'\0'`. This is what `printf()` does when you give it a `"%s"` format.

That anonymous array object, associated with the string literal, is read-only, but not `const`. What that means is that any attempt to modify that array, or any of its elements, has undefined behavior (because the standard explicitly says so) -- but the compiler won't necessarily warn you about it. (C++ makes string literals `const`; doing the same thing in C would have broken existing code that was written before `const` was added to the language.) So no, you can't modify the elements of `"hello"` -- or at least you shouldn't try. And to make the compiler warn you if you try, you should declare the pointer as `const`:

```
const char *ptr; /* pointer to const char, not const pointer to char */
ptr = "hello";
```

(gcc has an option, `-Wwrite-strings`, that causes it to treat string literals as `const`. This will cause it to warn about some C code that's legal as far as the standard is concerned, but such code should probably be modified to use `const`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
   char * ptr;

   ptr = "hello"; 

  //instead of above tow lines you can write char *ptr = "hello" 

   printf("%p %s" ,"hello",ptr );

   getchar();

}
```

Here you have assigned string literal `"hello"` to `ptr` it means string literal is stored in read only memory so you can't modify it. If you declare `char ptr[] = "hello";`, then you can modify the array.

Answer (score -2):

Say what?

Your code allocates 6 bytes of memory and initializes it with the values 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', and '\0'.

It then allocates a pointer (number of bytes for the pointer depends on implementation) and sets the pointer's value to the start of the 5 bytes mentioned previously.

You can modify the values of an array using syntax such as `ptr[1] = 'a'`.

Syntactically, strings are a special case. Since C doesn't have a specific string type to speak of, it does offer some shortcuts to declaring them and such. But you can easily create the same type of structure as you did for a string using `int`, even if the syntax must be a bit different.

Comment: `ptr[1] = 'a';`  may or may not execute and/or may or may not modify the value of 'e' to 'a' in the string. Most modern systems (Linux, MacOS X, Windows NT,2K,XP etc - not sure on Win98, etc) will fault when you do that, since it's "read only memory".

Comment: Which is why I worded in the more generic term "modify the values of an array", so as to avoid questions about access, which is really a different issue altogether.